# Is there something genuinely wrong with my answers?

Tags: support, answers, downvotes

I'm not sure if this is the "norm" or not, but I'd just like to get a second opinion. Two of my answers last night were DV'd, so naturally I assumed there must be something wrong with my posts (the DV's was 6 hours apart and it's only those two posts, so I wouldn't class this as serial DV'ing, so it seems perfectly genuine to me).

I checked them out, but as far as I can tell they're absolutely fine. I can't tell what's wrong - it doesn't help that the DV'er didn't leave a comment.

Here's the posts,

- [How can I record audio to a .flac file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588869/how-can-i-record-audio-to-a-flac-file/24595899#24595899),
- [Create valid “wav” file header for streams in memory using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695723/create-valid-wav-file-header-for-streams-in-memory-using-c-sharp/24435749#24435749).

Can you see anything incorrect? I'm not fussed over the rep (only -4, who cares?), I'm more concerned about the validity of my answers, hance me asking here for a second opinion...

Comment: Yeah, link us to get serial DV! Kidding, but the generic `[program 1 name]` thing makes me sick ;)

Comment: For the record, it took me all of 5 seconds to find the question even without a direct link...

Comment: One thing: If you are unsure that your answer is valid, don't post it. If you are sure then don't worry about an [occasional downvote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263089/is-my-answer-twisted-in-a-way-that-people-misunderstand-it)

Comment: @mehow I was positive that my answers were valid, I just didn't know if the DV's were genuine or not.

Comment: @Payeli Ok, thanks. So, nothing else besides that?

Comment: It's also debatable if the first question is on topic for SO, and some people downvote answers on questions that are off topic. Because you shouldn't answer questions that are meant to be closed. But. Just guessing here. That's all we really can do.

Comment: @J.Steen I do avoid posting answers to soon-to-be closed posts, but could you explain how that question would be classed as off-topic (agreed, it does seem to be "borderlining", but I would say completly off-topic)?

Comment: @Sam It wasn't my downvote, and I was only speculating anyway, so I couldn't possibly say with any certainty. Which is also why I haven't voted to close it. However. It's about the usage of a sound-recording software/utility. It's not *really* programming/code related, is it? Or am I missing something that's obvious to the initiated?

Comment: @J.Steen Right ok, so I suppose this applies to 3 party libs as well, or is it only software that isn't directly related to coding?

Comment: It's fairly simple (if up to some interpretation): Does it fall within [the scope of on-topic questions listed in the Stack Overflow help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @J.Steen Technically, I guess it would do; yeah it is quite simple, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. As I know nothing about the utility in question, I'm not voting to close. Just offering up suggestions and speculation. I'm very good at speculation, often even baseless! ;)

Comment: The first question is completely off topic.  Don't answer off-topic questions, as it encourages them.

Comment: @Will Can you explain why exactly that question is off-topic? I don't see how it's *completely* off-topic, admittedly I'd say it is on the borderline though.

Comment: @Sam: Exactly what programming language are they using?

Comment: @Will Well, it's a batch script, so technically none.

Comment: @Sam: It has nothing to do with a batch script.  It is about recording audio with an application from the command line.  That's not programming.  The question belongs on SU or AskDifferent.  Any goddamned application can be run from the command line, that doesn't mean that doing so makes a question about using it sort-of batch scripty and therefore borderline on topic here. Come on, this ain't chinese math.

Comment: @Will Yeah, after re-reading the post I see what you mean. Do you think it would be a good idea for me to delete my answer; since, as you said, answering these sorts of posts just encourages them?

Comment: @Sam: Yeah.  I think that's best.  Also, vtc.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first answer, it depends how strictly you interpret the question.

- If you interpret it as "How can I record audio data encoded as flac?", then your answer is completely reasonable and solves the problem
- If you interpret it as "`sox` is supposed to be able to create flac files, how can I get my version to do so?", then your answer doesn't really hit the point.

Of course it's hard to know which interpretation the OP intended, and harder to know what future visitors with the "same" problem are trying to accomplish. Also their intentions might be misguided (XY-Problem), and your answer might solve the real problem.

So I think your answer is completely reasonable. But I can also see how someone could come to the question, read the answer, and think that it completely misses the point.

For the second answer I don't really know enough about WAV processing in C# to judge it, but for example if there is some official API function that does the same thing, then someone might have thought "Oh no, don't write your own buggy implementation of this, that's a horrible idea! Use the well tested library function that handles all the corner cases you are missing!".

Comment: @Sam: A link and a short example how to use the official API would be a good answer, I think. If it does exactly what is requires I'd say it's likely the best way to solve the problem. But of course that depends on the specific case. If that official API doesn't really fit the question and needs some extra effort to be applied to the question, then a custom solution might be better. Also, generally, an answer is not necessarily *bad*, just because a different answer would be better.

Comment: The answer came 3 months after the comment (by Hans Passant) explaining how to do it with the official API.